# Node.js AWS deployment Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to upload a simple Node?JS app onto elastic beanstalk. All dependencies are listed in my package.json file and the app is listening on 8081 through nginx proxy.

The following error is being thrown from the node log file. Are the modules placed differently on the server ?

> Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/ module.js:471
>       throw err;
>        './routes/FtseData'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/var/app/current/routes.js:7:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) module.js:471
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './routes/FtseData'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/var/app/current/routes.js:7:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) module.js:471
>       throw err;
>       ^

Here is my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors()); 

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//    res.send('Hello World');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
})

var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', routes);


var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth')
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//var profCtrl = require('./routes/profileController');
var ftseDataCtrl = require('./routes/FtseData');
var ftseDivCtrl = require('./routes/FtseDiv');

//routes not needing auth
router.route('/FtseDivGet').get(ftseDivCtrl.get);
//routes needing auth
 router.use(basicAuth({
     users: { 'admin': 'supersecret' }
 }))
//router.route('/FtseDataScrape').get(ftseDataCtrl.scrape);
router.route('/FtseDivScrape').get(ftseDivCtrl.scrape);
//http://localhost:8081/api/profile

module.exports = router;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "StockTracker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Stock-Tracker",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "express-basic-auth": "*",
    "request": "*",
    "cheerio": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "cheerio-tableparser": "*",
    "cors": "*",
    "csv-load-sync": "*"        
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `require('./FtseData')` instead of `require('./routes/FtseData')` if `FTseData`  is in `routes`  folder, and `routes.js` is also in same routes folder

Comment: routes.js is in the root folder with server.js. FtseData.js is located in /routes folder. If i had the path wrong it wouldnt work on my local machine, but it does

Comment: i had to put the file extension on require statement.  require('./routes/FtseData'); to be require('./routes/FtseData.js');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My file was /routes/FtseData.js

This caused the error

```
var ftseDataCtrl = require('./routes/FTSEData');
```

Case needed to match file

```
var ftseDataCtrl = require('./routes/FtseData');
```

Comment: But the nodejs doc suggest that it will automatically try to add .js , .json and finally .node [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

Comment: I have tested it again. Your are correct. The issue appears to be casing in the filename. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question.